# Rails Migration Missing Column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I'm trying to rename a column that is definitely there in the schema and all the info is there, but when I go to update it it's giving me a "missing column" error and I can't figure out why? Any ideas?

Migration:

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :postcodes, :type, :zip_type
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "postcodes", force: true do |t|
     t.string   "postalcode"
     t.string   "type"
     t.string   "primary_city"
     t.string   "state"
     t.string   "county"
     t.string   "timezone"
     t.string   "area_code"
     t.string   "latitude"
     t.string   "longitude"
     t.string   "estimated_population"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
   end
```

Error:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
== 20150304172437 ChangeColumnName: migrating =================================
-- rename_column(:postcodes, :type, :zip_type)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Missing column postcodes.typeC:/Users/Steve    Q/Documents/GitHub/project1/db/migrate/20150304172437_change_column_name.rb:3:in `change'C:in `migrate' ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: Missing column postcodes.type
```

Comment: Maybe you renamed this column already. Check columns in your DB.

Comment: Try this in rails console `Postcode.last` and past the output here.

Comment: So the column is definitely that name. I don't have any records in there yet because "type" is a reserved word in rails which is why I want to change it. Until I change it I can't submit data to create a record...catch 22

Comment: now I'm getting this error in activeadmin ExecJS::ProgramError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new  not sure wha'ts going on there either.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried renaming `type` column to `zip_type` its working. Another solution is you can delete `type` column and add new column as `zip_type`.